# Regarding measurements on traveling microscope

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, measurements, microscopy, optical-materials

In a experiment with **traveling microscope** to determine thickness of a glass slab , what is the **physical significance** of the readings that we get from the vertical scale ?, Means What are two points between which the length is measured in vertical scale?

suppose I pleased an object (ie; a cross mark) and by adjusting the microscope to required Focus I got 75.99mm in vertical scale then from **what** to **what** the **distance** (ie; length) is measured in vertical scale?

Answer (score 1):

A traveling microscope is essentially a microscope-assisted vernier caliper. When you use a vernier caliper, you 'hold' the sample with the two arms of the caliper, and the distance between the arms will be the thickness of the sample. But for delicate samples like glass slides, we prefer a contactless way of measurement. So instead of arms, we use a microscope.

[image]

Once the top side of the glass slide is focused and aligned to the crosshair, we move the microscope downwards, till the bottom surface is in focus and aligned to the crosshair. The distance the microscope has moved will be then equal to the thickness of the glass slide. This distance is what we measure using the vertical vernier scale. Since the vernier scale is fixed, we will have to note down the vernier readings corresponding to both the surfaces, and then take its difference to find the thickness.